# send sql server mail network attachment

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, attachment

im having some issues sending an email with attachments.

i have to servers one is the .net server with asp.net 4.5 framework and the second is the databse server, sql server 2012 on a windows server 2012.

i write files via asp.net to the webserver, then i created a network drive to the web server on the database server.

but when i try to send the mail using this, i get the "Msg 22051 file is not valid" can you help me pls

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name='adsertitask',
@recipients='panchtzin@hotmail.com',
@subject='Test Attachment',
@body='An attachement has been included in this email.',
@file_attachments='c$\Users\admin\Desktop\loquesea.txt'
```

the configuration is like this,
web server: local path -> c:\certificados
database server: network driver z:(\192.168.13.13\certificados)
how can i send the file "prueba.txt" on 192.168.13.13\certificados path 
Thank you.

Comment: Why the $ (c$\)  Surely just C:\Users.....

Comment: i tried the 'C:\USers...' anmd nothing

Comment: Remember that it needs to be in the context of the SQL Server, i.e. C:\Users... is on the SQL Servers' drive.  Sorry if I am stating the obvious.

Comment: Sorry - '\\server\c$\users....' or '\\127.0.0.1\c$\users....' if it is the local server

Comment: \\¿SERVERNAME or ip?10.10.2.213\¿Network drive? z:\filename (loquesea.txt)

Comment: Either. Doesn't matter.  If it is local, then use 127.0.0.1 (local loopback bypasses the network - sort-of).  I would just refer to the \\ip\{drive}$\{path}\loquesea.txt.  You have no guarantee that the mapped drives are there.  (127.0.0.1 is the same as "MyPC")